# Learning Pygame, Why won't this 'raindrop' (Rect object) fall?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a [purple rain program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkyIDI6rQJI) in python using pygame. I made a class called Rain that I will use to make multiple rain drops but I tried testing if only 1 rain object would fall but..it didn't and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. While this may be a nooby and super obvious question, please keep in mind that I'm still learning pygame and python so..here's my code.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import random

pygame.init()

FPS = 60

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
PURPLE = (130, 50, 200)

screen_resolution = (800, 600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_resolution)

pygame.display.set_caption('Purple Rain')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gameLoop = True

class Rain:

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, yspeed):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.yspeed = yspeed
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def fall(self):
        self.rect.move(self.x, self.y - self.yspeed)
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, PURPLE, self.rect)
drop = Rain(400,300,2,20,9)
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    drop.draw()
    drop.fall()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369112/rect-move-does-not-move-the-rect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.rect.move(self.x, self.y - self.yspeed)` returns a new rectangle, but doesn't change the current one.

You want to do `self.rect.move_ip(0, - self.yspeed)` so the `self.rect` object is updated.

(and the parameters are offsets, not absolute coordinates)